# What does a backslash followed by a single quote mean in a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

Looking at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973896/emacs-org-mode-file-viewer-associations#3985552) on an old way for specifying the `org-file-apps` list, I can see that there is a backslash followed by a single-quote character after each file type extension, e.g. ...`pdf\\'"`...

What does it mean? What purpose does the backslash plus quote serve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a special construct in emacs regexp that matches the end of a string (not just the end of a line). Quoting the [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)

> \'
>
> matches the empty string, but only at the end of the string or buffer (or its accessible portion) being matched against.